# How can I install ziparchive on php 7.4?

Tags: php, apache, php-ziparchive, php-7.4, virtualmin

I am running Virtuamin on centos 7, I am unable to install ziparchive on php 7.4, but when I switch to php 7.2, it works. I need php 7.4 to work because it is faster and wordpress script need 7.3+ to work effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on Debian 9, which does not ship with PHP7.4, but it can be installed if you add the repository from Sury.

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https
wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

After that, I ran this with success:

```
apt install php7.4-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php7.4-zip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 94.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 php7.4-zip amd64 7.4.7-1+                                                                           0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911 [20.5 kB]
Fetched 20.5 kB in 0s (149 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package php7.4-zip.
(Reading database ... 107553 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php7.4-zip_7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911_amd                                                                           64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.4-zip (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911) ...
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.g                                                                           bp671911) ...
Setting up php7.4-zip (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911) ...
Creating config file /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/zip.ini with new version
Processing triggers for php7.4-fpm (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911) .                                                                           ..
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.g                                                                           bp671911) ...
Processing triggers for php7.4-cgi (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911) .                                                                           ..
Processing triggers for php7.4-cli (7.4.7-1+0~20200612.18+debian9~1.gbp671911) .                                                                           ..
```

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip
```

This works in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you would like to take a look on this post:
https://www.cloudbooklet.com/upgrade-php-version-to-php-7-4-on-ubuntu/

Basically, it tells you to:

Add PPA for PHP 7.4
Add the ondrej/php which has PHP 7.4 package and other required PHP extensions.

```sh
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Then you can install the extension

```sh
sudo apt install php7.4-zip
```

Or install all the commonly used ones:

```sh
sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I installed it on my ubuntu:-

For PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

For Centos

```
You can try: yum install php-pecl-zip.x86_64

Try installing that and enabling it by running: echo "extension=zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

**NOTE: Make sure to restart your server after install the above**

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart or sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: I am running centos not ubuntu, ziparchive is already installed for php 7.2, i need that to work on php 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of PHP you have, actually.  Generally, you would expect this to be all that is needed, especially since it runs: `sudo apt-get install php-zip`, but this didn't work for me.  The solution is PHP-version dependent.

For the three major versions of PHP available right now, the last one here (which actually matches my version 8.1) worked for me:

#### PHP 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

#### PHP 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

#### PHP 8.0

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-zip
```

#### And don't forget to restart apache after installing!

One of these should restart Apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 graceful
```